# Alphabetic search using the Javascript array sort() method and a compare function

Tags: javascript

Here is a reverse alphabetic search using the `sort()` method

Notice that a `compareFunction` is supplied as mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
function reverseAlpha(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log('a:' + a);
    console.log('b:' + b);
    if (a === b) {
      return 0;
    } else if (a < b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  });
}

console.log(reverseAlpha(['l', 'h', 'z', 'b', 's'])); // Returns ['z', 's', 'l', 'h', 'b']
```

Now consider the following for an alphabetic search:

```
function alphaSort(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log('a:' + a);
    console.log('b:' + b);
    if (a === b) {
      return 0;
    } else if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });
}

console.log(alphaSort(['l', 'h', 'z', 'b', 's'])); // Returns ['b', 'h', 'l', 's', 'z']
```

My question is this, by simply swapping the last two `return` values of the `else if...` `else` conditions to:

```
else if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
```

How does this result in the sort reversing and becoming alphabetic? I think that this achieves an alphabetic search because we are just swapping this logic around with the conditions:

-If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b` (i.e. `a` comes first)

-If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns greater than 0, sort `b` to an index lower than `a` (i.e. `b` comes first).

Comment: btw, after `return`, you need no `else`, like `if () return; if () return;`.

Comment: I suspect you're doing this for an exercise, but FWIW, when comparing strings like that, you can use `localeCompare`: `.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))` is alpha ascending, `.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))` (or `.sort((a, b) => -a.localeCompare(b))`) is alpha descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this, by simply swapping the last two return values of the else if... else conditions... How does this result in the sort reversing and becoming alphabetic?

Because in the first block you're returning:

- 0  if a === b
- 1 if a < b
- -1  if a > b

but in the second block you're returning

- 0  if a === b
- **-1** if a < b
- **1**  if a > b

You've changed what you're telling the `sort` function about how `a` and `b` relate to each other. The return value from the callback is what tells the `sort` function how those elements relate to each other: If you return -1, it means `a` should go before `b` in the sorted result. If you return 1, it means `a` should go after `b` in the sorted result.

**If** you wanted to change the order of those return statements *without* changing what the `sort` function did, you'd *also* have to change the `else if (a < b)` to `else if (a > b)` so you're returning the same information.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer @T.J. Crowder it was very insightful